# gif images rendering then disappear chrome

Tags: google-chrome, gif

Gif images render for a split second, when page is fully loaded then disappear leaving the broken image icon. This happens only in Chrome other browsers it's fine including Safari.

The weird thing is all has been fine and working perfectly for months up until last night.

Chrome's web developer tool reads 'Failed to load resource'.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

A link to a page is below.

Thanks,

http://www.isenterprises.co.uk/product_info.php?cPath=33_46&products_id=748

(it's the 'Colours Available' colour swatches that don't render properly)

Comment: Works for me, Chrome 21.0.1180.57 beta

Comment: Works on Chrome 20.0.1132.57 m, Windows 7. You may have a plugin or browser add-on like an ad blocker that is interfering with the image rendering.

Comment: I think it's a proxy server issue our end.  Thanks for the input:)

Answer (score 1):

In fact IE doesn't know who "Transfer-Encoding" is. You will have to write:

```
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: deflate');
```

in `paps_makethumb.php`.

Answer (score 0):

Add:

```
header('Transfer-Encoding: deflate');
```

in `paps_makethumb.php`

Comment: Hi Mihai,thanks for your suggestion it corrected the Chrome issue however adding the line of your code made the images not appear in I.E.  I think it's a proxy server issue our end

Answer (score 0):

Same issue for me, solved by removing Chrome **extensions**!

- Chrome menu Chrome menu > Settings.
- Click Extensions.

Check what's in there... I had to uninstall "QR Code generator" previously installed.
Maybe some extensions need to be updated, but i uninstalled them and now Chrome renders well.