# gif doesn't display in Chrome when loaded while not visible

Tags: html, css, gif

I'm loading a form with ajax, and this form has a submit button. When I press that button, the button disappear, and a gif is displayed to indicate process while the form is submitted. The gif isn't visible when the form is loaded in with AJAX.

The problem is that when the submit button is pressed, the gif doesn't show. If I go in Chrome Dev Tools and check the css, it is all correct, and if I tick off and on any css property belonging to the gif, it suddenly shows up. It is like it just isn't rendered, because Chrome can find it on the server.

This is the css for the gif:

```
.form_wrapper .loading_gif {
    background: url("../images/loader_blue.gif") no-repeat;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It works perfectly in FF.

This is the html I keep the div in:

```
<div class="application_submited" id="application_submited">
    <div class="center">
        <div class="loading_gif"></div>
        <span>For submitting. Please wait.</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

The CSS for `.center`:

```
.center {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0px auto;
    width: 90%;
    line-height: 45px;
    height: 45px;
}
```

I've added `.center`. Z-idex on the gif does not help. It is really strange, when I switch to the other gif, it works, when I use this one, it doesn't display.

Comment: Try display: block; visibility: visible;

Comment: what you have been using to hide the gif initially, display:none; or visibility:hidden;

Comment: @shadow `display: none`, but not on the gif it self, on a parent div.

Comment: @C-Link That doesn't work, but thanks anyway.

Comment: that div contains only the gif?

Comment: @shadow Added the html to the opening post, don't have time to post all the css now, but it is the `application_submited` which is hidden.

Comment: you have added display:none to div class="center" ? can you upload css for class center

Comment: Please use z-index:99; in your <div class="loading_gif"></div>

Comment: I've added `.center`. Z-idex on the gif does not help. It is really strange, when I switch to the other gif, it works, when I use this one, it doesn't display.

Comment: Take a look at this issue, i think it could help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11776448/gif-images-rendering-then-disappear-chrome/23145488#23145488